# How to get my computer external IP address?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Lets say my IP currently is: `123.123.123.123`

How can I get that string programmatically?

Note: I don't want to get this IP: `192.168.0.10`, I want that IP which others can use to connect into my computer via HTTP or anything.

NOTE: I dont want to open some web-page such as ip4.me to get the address, I want to get it with just C++.

I tried to google but every suggestion was "load a page and read the IP it tells you". Is that really the only way?!

Comment: The only other way is to somehow query the thing that connects you to the internet (like your DSL router/modem). There is no generic interface for this. Might be some libraries, but nothing in standard C++.

Comment: How at you connected? At work we have 2 or 3 IP-addresses shared by 10.000 people. Knowing the external address isn't useful in that case.

Comment: There's no API to do this, because your computer simply *doesn't know* what the external IP address is.  Windows can't give you information it doesn't have.  Why do you need the external address anyway?

Comment: @BoPersson, if its not useful to you, doesnt mean its not useful to anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch it from http://api.externalip.net/ip/ or some similar services, but I'm not sure how reliable these sites are, in means of availability

Any other way would be extremely complicated, as in general, no network equipment has api to tell external IP, and even if it had,  you can not tell is there a simple xDSL router in front of you or Cisco ASA nating outbound traffic

Comment: What other websites you know, that returns only the IP and nothing else, so its easy to parse? (it could be smart to have a fall-back sites, if one of those doesnt work).

Comment: Sure, fallbacks should be obligatory in this case... http://checkip.dyndns.org/ should be easy to parse, http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp is ip addr only too

Comment: Have a look at this, Google has a service for getting your IP http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1696588 I don't have experience with google API, but it is worth to try, at least you can be sure it will always respond

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to send a packet with the record route option.

If you know your upstream gateway, you should be able to find a ping command that allows you to set record route, and then either stores that data in an array or something you can regex.

Your WAN IP should be either record 0 or record 1, I believe.

What network library are you using?

Comment: Hrm.  You might want to look at something higher-layer than winsock.  Here's a workaround. `out = system("ping -r 9 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");` (use the gateway your router connects to for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.  You may be able to use others further out, but I know it doesn't work on a Mac) You can see what this returns by running the command.  The important line reads `Route: host [you.rwa.nip.hre]` A grep will get you that information at that point.